# findAll() method of ReactiveRepository on Spring-boot doesn't return all documents. It returns only 10 documents

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to retrieve all documents with reactive repository on Spring-boot. But findAll only returns 10 documents...

Sample Code:

```
@Repository
interface DocRepository : ReactiveElasticsearchRepository<Doc, String> {}

@Document(indexName="test")
class Doc{ 
   @Id
   String id;
   String name;
}
docRepo : DocRepository
docRepo.findAll()<=== Only returns 10 documents
```

How can I retrieve all documents? .. tried take(N) method but doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's default, you can use like _docRepo.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 200))_ or more. Fetching all data will give you very bad performace in real senerio.

Comment: @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks ReactiveRepository doesn't support PageRequest. :(

Comment: As per the document you can https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters but not using ReactiveElasticsearchRepository obviously. And found details here also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/reactive-elasticsearch-repositories.adoc using ReactiveSortingRepository

Comment: Thank you solved. with ```docRepo.findById(null, PageRequest(1,200))```

Comment: Did you try adding method in the repository like `List<Doc> findAll(Pageable pageable);` ? And just call like in my first comment.

Comment: @Eklavya-UpvoteDon'tSayThanks Yes, I tried. But I encountered an ```exception.org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. with

docRepo.findById(null, PageRequest(1,200))